# Is it possible to create a binary non-unique tree using the preorder and postorder sequences?

Tags: data-structures

Is it possible to create a binary non-unique tree using the preorder and postorder sequences ?
If so, how can this be done ? For example how could I make a non-unique tree for:

Preorder:

```
B C I J K H D E F G
```

Postorder:

```
I H K J C G F E D B
```

How many could there be ?

Comment: You can construct a unique Binary Search Tree given any two traversals, are you looking to do that or are you in search of something else?
If not please elaborate what you mean by non unique trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preorder psedo-code:

```
preorder (tree)
{
    if tree isn't empty then
    {
        print key[tree]
        preorder left[tree]
        preorder right[tree]
    }
}
```

and post order is:

```
postorder (tree)
{
    if tree isn't empty then
    {
        preorder left[tree]
        preorder right[tree]
        print key[tree]
    }
}
```

so from inorder order we can conclude:

- "B" must be the root
- "C" must be "B"'s child
- "G" must be the the max value (the most far right node in the tree) or the min value in the left sub-tree (the most far left node in the left sub-tree) - in that case "G" must be a leaf and "F" must be "G"'s parent

and from postorder order we can conclude:

- "I" must be a leaf and the min value (the most right node in the tree).
- "H" must be "I"'s parent ("I" is "H" left child) in case I has no children, else "H" is the next far left child in the tree.

from here it's like a Sudoku:

[image]
and yes: by using preorder and postorder outputs you can build a tree in only one way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to construct different binary trees that have the same pre- and postorder sequences. To generate such different trees, look for subtrees where either the left or the right child is empty and simply swap the children.

This minimal example

```
  a         a
 /    vs.    \
b             b
```

shows two trees that both have the preordering `a b` and the postordering `b a`.